# buildroot package from local source with snapshots

Tags: buildroot

I want to fork buildroot, add a custom package, add the package's source directly in-tree, and have buildroot use the in-tree source to build the custom package. I've done that, following [chapter 17 of the buildroot user manual](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#adding-packages), but **buildroot doesn't seem to be picking up local changes that I've made**.

For example, I built the entire image, and it also built my custom application. Then I went into the source for my custom application and added an intentional syntax error -- but then I ran make again and it happily generated an image *using the old version of my custom app*.

**How do I tell buildroot to look for local source modifications, even if it already has a cached build of the package with a matching version?**

These are the new files which I have added to my buildroot fork:

```
buildroot/
  package/
    customapp/
      customapp.mk
      Config.in
  customapp/
    configure.ac
    Makefile.am
    README
    src/
      main.c
      Makefile.am
```

(I also edited `buildroot/package/Config.in` so that it sources the `buildroot/package/customapp/Config.in` file. All the Config.in stuff is just a simple boolean to enable customapp, and they work fine, so I'll omit them from this question.)

Here are the contents of the build-related files:

> buildroot/package/customapp/customapp.mk

```
CUSTOMAPP_VERSION = 0.1
CUSTOMAPP_SITE = customapp
CUSTOMAPP_SITE_METHOD = local
CUSTOMAPP_AUTORECONF = YES

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

> buildroot/customapp/configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([customapp], [0.1], [name@email.tld])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

> buildroot/customapp/Makefile.am

```
SUBDIRS = src
dist_doc_DATA = README
```

> buildroot/customapp/src/Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = customapp
customapp_SOURCES = main.c
```

Comment: i recall that, in maven, i need to specify the version as "SNAPSHOT" so the build system knows to check for modifications to the source. obviously, this isn't maven, but do i need to do something similar here?

Comment: `make` does not require a special flag to check whether a target is older than its dependencies.  Doing so is one of its core behaviors.  Some implementations, including GNU's, offer an option to rebuild targets even if they are already newer than their dependencies, but I'm not aware of any that have an option to *avoid* rebuilding targets that are out of date, and surely none do that by default.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you! i'm aware of make's behavior; in this case, i believe this is a behavior of buildroot. buildroot has pretty aggressive caching, and it usually doesn't even look at the source if it already has a compiled version whose version number matches the version specified in `buildroot/package/customapp/customapp.mk`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger in that way, buildroot is similar to maven, so i thought perhaps there is some sort of "SNAPSHOT" option that i need to specify... but i don't know where or how to search for it.

Comment: I'm not much of a buildroot guy, but according to [the documentation](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg), to rebuild customapp after it has been built, you should start by performing `make customapp-rebuild`.  You make then either `make customapp` or just `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 8.3](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg) of the buildroot manual explains how to rebuild a single package.  The easiest way is with `[package name]-rebuild` target.  In your case it would be:

```
make customapp-rebuild
```

You may want to also trigger the buildroot post build actions to rebuild the target device file system images after your package re-build is complete:

```
make target-post-image
```

Answer (score 0):

To rebuild a buildroot package, you have to remove the stamp files in output/build/customapp-version/.stamp*. The easiest way is to remove the whole build directory.

Buildroot relies only on the .stamp files for understanding what needs to be rebuild.